# Why ZipEntry shows incorrect compilation time of APK file?

Tags: java, android

Im using this code to show App compilation date:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = a.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(a.getPackageName(), 0);
        ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(ai.sourceDir);
        ZipEntry ze = zf.getEntry("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
        long time = ze.getTime() + (3600000 * 2);
        Log.i("date", new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date(time)));
        zf.close();
```

Yesterday everything was fine but today (after Android Studio upgrade ???) everytime It shows

> 02:00:00 30.11.1979

???
I have already Cleaned and Rebuilt project.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Why are you adding `3600000 * 2` to the time? 83.3333 days? And since when is the manifest date the compilation date?

Comment: I was using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979806/display-the-android-application-apk-creation-date-in-application

Comment: There is nothing there about either using the manifest date as the compilation date or adding `3600000 * 2` to the time.

Comment: adding 3600000 * 2 was just for me, nevermind

Comment: yeap, AS clearing needed option when Gradle updating.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have an answer from: [How to write build time stamp into apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607165/how-to-write-build-time-stamp-into-apk)

Best option is using Timestamp in Gradle

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "long", "TIMESTAMP", System.currentTimeMillis() + "L"
}
```

}

```
Date buildDate = new Date(BuildConfig.TIMESTAMP);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [response #3 on this Google Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37116029#comment3), the ZipFile method of obtaining the build date can still be used as long as "android.keepTimestampsInApk = true" is set in Gradle properties.

Gradle intentionally zeroes out the build timestamps unless that property is set.